# JButtons are not being disabled when setEnabled(false); is called

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, frame

So in this application, I have the option to create my own burgers but also have 3 commonly ordered burgers that can be selected and added to the order without building them from scratch. At the moment, I can build my own burger but also click on one of the favorite burger buttons and that causes a mix up in the orders. I want to make it so that when I click on `beef`, `chicken`, or `fish` buttons,the special order buttons will be disabled and I tried doing that by calling a method that sets all of them to setEnabled(false) and then another method to enable them once the burger being created is added. However, this isn't working as intended and the favburger buttons are never disabled. Why's that? What can I do to fix this?

```
import javax.swing.*;

import se.umu.cs.apjava.maxdonalds.burger.AbstractFactory;
import se.umu.cs.apjava.maxdonalds.burger.FavBurger;

import java.awt.*;

public class MaxDonaldsGuiBuilder {

private JCheckBox withKetchupButton;
private JCheckBox withMayoButton;
private BurgerOrderModel burgerOrderModel;
private ButtonGroup burgerGroup;
private JCheckBox withAioliButton;
private JCheckBox withTomatoButton;
private JCheckBox withPicklesButton;
private JCheckBox withLettuceButton;
private JButton favBurger1;
private JButton favBurger2;
private JButton favBurger3;

void buildGui() {
    burgerOrderModel = new BurgerOrderModel();
    var frame=new JFrame("MaxDonalds");


    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JComponent burgerPanel = buildBurgerPanel();
    JComponent orderPanel = buildOrderPanel(textArea);
    JComponent additionsPanel = buildSaucesPanel();
    JComponent vegetablesPanel = buildVegetablesPanel();
    JComponent favoriteBurgerPanel = favBurgerPanel();
    var topPanel=new JPanel();
    topPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,50));
    topPanel.add(burgerPanel);
    topPanel.add(vegetablesPanel);
    topPanel.add(additionsPanel);
    topPanel.add(favoriteBurgerPanel);

    topPanel.add(orderPanel);
    frame.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,400));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    favBurger1 = new JButton();
    favBurger2 = new JButton();
    favBurger3 = new JButton();


}

private JComponent buildOrderPanel(JTextArea textArea) {
    Box orderPanel=new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    var printButton = new JButton("Print Order");
    printButton.addActionListener(e->{
        String orderString= burgerOrderModel.getOrderString();
        textArea.append(orderString);

    });
    var addButton = new JButton("Add Burger To Order");
    addButton.addActionListener(e->{
        if (burgerGroup.getSelection() == null) {
            burgerOrderModel.setType("Beef");
        }
        burgerOrderModel.addBurgerToOrder();
        //Enable the specials buttons again.
        enableSpecials();
        clearSelection();
    });
    orderPanel.add(addButton);
    orderPanel.add(printButton);
    orderPanel.add(Box.createGlue());
    return orderPanel;
}

private JComponent buildSaucesPanel() {
    var additionsPanel=new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    JLabel additions = new JLabel("Sauces");
    additions.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    additionsPanel.add(additions);
    withKetchupButton = new JCheckBox("Ketchup");
    withKetchupButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    withKetchupButton.addChangeListener(e->
        burgerOrderModel.setWithKetchup(withKetchupButton.isSelected())
    );
    additionsPanel.add(withKetchupButton);
    withMayoButton = new JCheckBox("Mayo");
    withMayoButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    withMayoButton.addChangeListener(e->
        burgerOrderModel.setWithMayo(withMayoButton.isSelected())
    );
    additionsPanel.add(withMayoButton);
    withAioliButton = new JCheckBox("Aioli");
    withAioliButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    withAioliButton.addChangeListener(e->
        burgerOrderModel.setWithAioli(withAioliButton.isSelected())
    );
    additionsPanel.add(withAioliButton);
    JComponent withTextPanel = getTextPanel();
    additionsPanel.add(withTextPanel);
    additionsPanel.add(Box.createGlue());
    return additionsPanel;
}

private JComponent buildVegetablesPanel() {
    var additionsPanel=new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    JLabel additions = new JLabel("Vegetables");
    additions.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    additionsPanel.add(additions);
    withLettuceButton = new JCheckBox("Lettuce");
    withLettuceButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    withLettuceButton.addChangeListener(e->
        burgerOrderModel.setWithLettuce(withLettuceButton.isSelected())
    );
    additionsPanel.add(withLettuceButton);
    withTomatoButton = new JCheckBox("Tomato");
    withTomatoButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    withTomatoButton.addChangeListener(e->
        burgerOrderModel.setWithTomato(withTomatoButton.isSelected())
    );
    additionsPanel.add(withTomatoButton);
    withPicklesButton = new JCheckBox("Pickles");
    withPicklesButton.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    withPicklesButton.addChangeListener(e->
        burgerOrderModel.setWithPickles(withPicklesButton.isSelected())
    );
    additionsPanel.add(withPicklesButton);
    JComponent withTextPanel = getTextPanel();
    additionsPanel.add(withTextPanel);
    additionsPanel.add(Box.createGlue());
    return additionsPanel;
}

private JComponent getTextPanel() {
    FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    layout.setHgap(0);
    layout.setVgap(0);
    var withTextPanel=new JPanel(layout);
    withTextPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    return withTextPanel;
}

private JComponent buildBurgerPanel() {
    var burgerPanel=new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    var chickenBurgerButton=new JRadioButton("ChickenBurger");
    chickenBurgerButton.addActionListener(e->{
        burgerOrderModel.setType("Chicken");
        //If the beef, chicken, or fish options are clicked, the favBurger buttons will be disabled.
        disableSpecials();
    });
    var beefBurgerButton=new JRadioButton("BeefBurger");
    beefBurgerButton.addActionListener(e->{
        burgerOrderModel.setType("Beef");
         disableSpecials();    
    });
    var fishBurgerButton = new JRadioButton("FishBurger");
    fishBurgerButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        burgerOrderModel.setType("Fish");
        disableSpecials();
    });
    burgerGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    burgerGroup.add(beefBurgerButton);
    burgerGroup.add(chickenBurgerButton);
    burgerGroup.add(fishBurgerButton);
    burgerPanel.add(new JLabel("Basic Burgers"));
    burgerPanel.add(beefBurgerButton);
    burgerPanel.add(chickenBurgerButton);
    burgerPanel.add(fishBurgerButton);
    return burgerPanel;
}

private void clearSelection() {
    withKetchupButton.setSelected(false);
    withMayoButton.setSelected(false);
    withAioliButton.setSelected(false);
    withTomatoButton.setSelected(false);
    withPicklesButton.setSelected(false);
    withLettuceButton.setSelected(false);
    burgerGroup.clearSelection();
}

private JComponent favBurgerPanel() 
{

    var favoriteBurgerPanel=new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    var favBurger1 = new JButton("Favorite Burger 1");
    favBurger1.addActionListener(e -> {
        burgerOrderModel.setType("special 1");
        burgerOrderModel.addBurgerToOrder();
        clearSelection();
    });
    var favBurger2 = new JButton("Favorite Burger 2");
    favBurger2.addActionListener(e -> {
        burgerOrderModel.setType("special 2");
        burgerOrderModel.addBurgerToOrder();
        clearSelection();
    });
    var favBurger3 = new JButton("Favorite Burger 3");
    favBurger3.addActionListener(e -> {
        burgerOrderModel.setType("special 3");
        burgerOrderModel.addBurgerToOrder();
        clearSelection();
    });

    favoriteBurgerPanel.add(new JLabel("Top Burgers"));
    favoriteBurgerPanel.add(favBurger1);
    favoriteBurgerPanel.add(favBurger2);
    favoriteBurgerPanel.add(favBurger3);
    return favoriteBurgerPanel;


}

private void enableSpecials()
{
    favBurger1.setEnabled(true);
    favBurger2.setEnabled(true);
    favBurger3.setEnabled(true);
}

private void disableSpecials()
{
    favBurger1.setEnabled(false);
    favBurger2.setEnabled(false);
    favBurger3.setEnabled(false);
}



}
```

Comment: You are shadowing your JButton variables, and so you are likely changing the state of the wrong instances. Don't re-declare the variables.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What do you mean by "shadowing"?

Comment: Look in this code how many times you have the statement `favBurger1 = new JButton();`. Each such statement creates a new and unique JButton instance, and changing the state of one, such as whether it is enabled or not, will have no effect on the other. Declare and initialize this and the similar variables *once* each.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Omg you're right... Feel so dumb rn haha. But thanks for pointing it out!